# Push notification, is it the device token all we need, or more?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm reading over [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141757/device-token-in-push-notification) because I was having a problem converting the device token to something I could send in a POST. That problem is solved, and my token is being sent properly to the server, which we store in a user's account record.

That is all I need to do, right? If we notify using that token, it will go to that user, and only that user? Or am I missing something really critical here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say 'user' do you mean that your app can have different users log in and out?

To handle this, you can set up a table to map `user_id` to `push_token` and `device_id`. You should also add an `enabled` flag to this map - which means the user is currently logged in on that device.

Conceptually, while a device has only one push token, it may have many users, and a user may have many devices.

When a user signs into your app on a device you send `user_id`, `push_token` and `device_id` and set `enabled=TRUE` in your table.  If this user/device combo never existed, add to your table.

When a user signs out of your app on a device you send `user_id` and `device_id` and set `enabled=FALSE` in your table.

When an event occurs that would trigger a push to user with `user_id` then you can look up what `push_tokens` are associated to that `user_id` and `enabled=TRUE`.  Then you can simply push to those tokens.

Comment: There is only one user per device, and they are only on one device at one time. The data in the app comes from a service which requires login on that service, it's a JSON server. So there are accounts on the server, although no one really "logs in or out", right now it's just a list of meaningless userids and their device tokens. I guess my question has to do with push_token and device_id. Are these not the same thing?

Comment: If the user has to log into the service, they could log in on two devices. This is why you need `device_id` as well.  `device_id` is essentially UDID - a unique identifier for the device.  Per the Apple docs, `push_token` is not guaranteed to remain fixed either.  Typically, its good to update it on every log in. Also, if a user logs out of the service and another logs in on the same device, then both will have the same `push_token`.  You don't want user1 getting pushes about user2's activity.  Similarly, you do want user1 getting push notifications on any device they are logged in to.

Comment: OK, but not knowing anything on the server side, what does the server have to send to Apple? Both of these, or can it do it with just one. Sadly I don't have a lot of control over the API.

Comment: The server just sends the `push_token` and the payload json

Answer (score 0):

@dmorrow is right. In addition, you need to make a .pem certificate with the same app id to make server push notifications work, check this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification)

Comment: I have the PEM already, we used it with Localytics... which I think answers my question because it could send messages to specific users.